# Indent of array in method in phpStorm

Tags: php, array, phpstorm

phpStorm is formatting arrays in method calls like this (auto code formatting):

```
$address = new Address([
                           'full_name' => $fullname,
                       ]);
```

I expect it to format like this:

```
$address = new Address([
    'full_name' => $fullname,
]);
```

phpStorm's settings are very well structured but I don't find this specific one..

Whats the option to let phpStorm auto format the arrays like in the second code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

It's here: Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | "Wrapping and Braces" tab | Array initializer | **Align when multiline**

[image]

Found it through those posts:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009831520-How-to-configure-auto-indent-multiline-function-parameters-in-short-array-?sort_by=created_at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044335/783119

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, spaces and other white chars are not parsed, but only used to know if letters are connected or not.

In PHP the following is identical:

```
if($expression==true){MyFunction();}
```

```
if( $expression == true )
{
    MyFunction();
}
```

And even:

```
if
    ($expression == true)
{
    MyFunction();
}
```

So why does one write it differently than others? Usually for readability. But all that matters is that it doesn't matter. You can edit it the way you are used to and it will still work.

Comment: Sorry, you missed the topic. We have strict code style rules (thank god) and my question is about how to fix this setting in phpStorm auto code formatter.

Comment: I had to guess what your question was because there wasn't any. So I assumed you were wondering why the spaces were different.

Comment: The question is passively formulated in the last sentence: "Where do I find the setting to let phpStorm properly format the code?" Thanks for your post tho, you tried to help, thanks for your time!

Comment: I misunderstood you because the php example code itself shows settings and I read it as "how can I change the code so it is structured like this" But with your edit, now it is more clear.